# How to sum elements for specific person (id) - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello how do i sum table column for specific person (id). For example i have a table like this(this is table ProjectHistory table): [image]

and i want to display in my colabs view, all sum with specific collaborator so for example look image below.(this is Collaborators table)[image]

so if u look at image i have the id 2 for "David" collab. so i want to output in the column "Suma" the sum of ProjectHistory table for colab with id 2, so ( 3 + 500 = 503 ). and i want to do that for all collabs. for example for colab_id 3 i want to display in "Colaboratori" view(for id 3 means Valentin) 2500+1800 = 4300. How do i do that? give me an idea please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sum` in the QueryBuilder.

Like so:

```
$data = ProjectHistory::where('id', 1)->sum('suma');
```

In your case, you may also use the `withSum` to obtain the result you want. Like so:

```
$data = Collaborator::withSum('ProjectHistory', 'suma')->get();
```

This resulting Collaborator will have an extra key now named: `projecthistory_sum_suma` which will have the sum of all the `suma` belonging to that Collaborator.

This of course assumes that you have a `hasMany` relation with the `ProjectHistory` model.

Comment: yes but i want to display it dinamically. so if i enter another collaborator to display the sum also for him.

Comment: i don't have hasMany relation with the ProjectHistory. so i need to make one

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Models\Colaboratori::IstoricProiect(),

Comment: i set this into my ProjectHistory model: 
public function Colaboratori()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Colaboratori::class);
    }

Comment: The relation needs to be in the Colaboratori model, and you should name it something like:
function historyprojects, you can then do: withSum('historyprojects', 'suma') in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relational model:

```
//In your Collaborator model

public function projectHistory()
{
   return $this->hasMany(ProjectHistory::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key'));
}

//In your Collaborator controlller

public function index()
{
  $collaborators = Collaborator::with('projectHistory')->get();
  return view('your_view', compact('collaborators');
}
```

Then add `projectHistory` in your view.

Comment: hey i tried ur method and i get Call to undefined relationship [IstoricProiecte] on model [App\Models\Colaboratori].